# How can I make boolean of a null in Angular and TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, types, casting, boolean

***Disclaimer:*** The question is about the feature of the language and not simply "how do I ...". Please note that I do have **working** code already - I just don't understand **why it's working**.

I've designed a method like this.

```
public static isSomething(input?: string): boolean {
  if (!input)
    return null !== pickParts1("default")
  return null !== pickParts2(input);
}

private static pickParts1(input: string) string[] { ... }

private static pickParts2(input: string) string[] { ... }
```

Simply put - if the result is an array (be that empty or not), I return true. If the result is *undefined* or *null*, I want to return false. The code above works but I'm confused why I can't simply return the result like this.

```
public static isSomething(input?: string): boolean {
  if (!input)
    return pickParts1("default")
  return pickParts2(input);
}
```

The reason why I expected it to work is that it apparently does so in the conditional if-part (as it did in JavaScript). Not sure why it doesn't cast to *boolean* for me here.

I tried casting by `(boolean)` and `as boolean` but apparently TypseScript believes that it's not a valid syntax (well, I **was** taking a whack and long shot). Is there a way to make it work?

And if someone wonders why I want to do it - because I'm amazed and curious about the language and want to test its limits.

Comment: In this specific example you can use `return !!pickParts1("default")`

Comment: @AlekseyL. Post that as a reply to be answered, please. (It's the same request as before but now posted on my account. I accidentally posted from a friends account because I'm leaching his computer and I'm too lazy to log him off.)

Answer (score 0):

If you specify `boolean` as return type, the compiler expects the value to be a `boolean` not a `string[]`.
If you specify return type `any`, you can return any type of value and the JS type coercion rules apply.

Comment: I think you can cast it to trick the compiler, but I think that's quite ugly. Either you want the benefit of types, then code accordingly, or you don't, than use `any` everywhere.